# Tensorflow - Nodedef difference between keys DTYPE and T

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to know what is the difference in the protobuf file of the graph between the attribute with keys "T" and "dtype"

For example for the add operator we have a key "T" with the type as value:

```
name: "conv1/truncated_normal"
op: "Add"
input: "conv1/truncated_normal/mul"
input: "conv1/truncated_normal/mean"
attr {
  key: "T"
  value {
    type: DT_FLOAT
  }
}
```

Whereas for constant we have in general "dtype" as key to specify the type :

```
name: "conv1/Const"
op: "Const"
attr {
  key: "dtype"
  value {
    type: DT_FLOAT
  }
}
attr {
  key: "value"
  value {
    tensor {
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      tensor_shape {
        dim {
          size: 32
        }
      }
      float_val: 0.10000000149011612
    }
  }
}
```

And for the TruncatedNormal we have both "T" and "dtype"

```
name: "conv2/truncated_normal/TruncatedNormal"
op: "TruncatedNormal"
input: "conv2/truncated_normal/shape"
attr {
  key: "T"
  value {
    type: DT_INT32
  }
}
attr {
  key: "dtype"
  value {
    type: DT_FLOAT
  }
}
attr {
  key: "seed"
  value {
    i: 0
  }
}
attr {
  key: "seed2"
  value {
    i: 0
  }
}
```

Thanks by advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for TruncatedNormal both T and dtype are "type" attributes. `shape` input argument takes its type from "T" and `output` takes its type from "dtype". Names "T" and "dtype" are arbitrary, an op creator could've called them "T1" and "T2" instead, which would be more natural.